# Reading from text file, empty lines is skipped

Tags: android, text-files, bufferedreader

Im writing an app where i read from the text file located in my assets folder.

Lets say my text file look like this.

```
1.Hello
2.
3.world
4.again
```

And i am using BufferedReader to read it line by line (i only want the three first).

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(result.getContext().getAssets().open("file.txt")));
        string text;
        for (int x=0;x<3; x++) {
            text += reader.readLine();
        }
```

Output becomes "helloworld". How do i get it to look like:

```
hello

world
```

I though BufferedReader included empty lines from a textfile :S.

I tried to manually create that line break i wanted with an if statement inside the for loop, like

```
            for (int x=0;x<4; x++) {
            String s = reader.readLine();
            if(s.equals("")){
                text+="\n";
            }else {
                text += s;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java documentation `BufferedReader#readLine()` returns:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

See [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

You have to add new line character manually in for loop as you proposed by checking for empty string.

Comment: The problem is that i have tried to locate a way to know if an empty line was read but but it seems like it cannot be tried. Neither of these will work> reader.readLine().isEmpty() //or > .equals("") (null) ("\n"). Maybe there is a better way to do what i want to do? My textfile have prob over 50 lines and is formatted like a book, which means it has line breaks to separate paragraphs. But when i display it in a textview those line breaks are not there.

Comment: If you don't appear to be seeing an empty String, either the line is not empty, or you are not testing for an empty String correctly. `if(reader.readLine().equals(""))` must work.